# Spark Worker "Died" status after zookeeper recovery for a new master

Tags: scala, apache-spark, virtual-machine, apache-zookeeper

I have successfully set up zookeeper and spark standalone in 3 different virtual box. Starting zookeeper and spark master is not a problem.

having IP address of on `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.1.10 master1
192.168.1.11 master2
192.168.1.12 master3
```

Upon starting my slaves (spark-workers) to connect to my masters using the code below on all machines.

`./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://master1:7077,master2:17077,master3:7077`

The 'slaves' (spark workers) are connected successfully on the first master but when I kill or stop the active master starts the recovery but after the recovery, only the worker having the same IP address of the current master is alive, leaving the other workers dead and killed after several minutes.

The project's location is both at `/usr/local/` under the user `spuser`

All ports needed are opened via

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=<port_number>/tcp --permanent`

#### Spark Configs

I also have a `/usr/local/spark/highavability.conf`

```
spark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER
spark.deploy.zookeeper.url=192.168.1.10:2181,192.168.1.11:2181,192.168.1.12:2181
spark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/usr/local/spark/spark
```

and running the master using on all machines

`./sbin/start-master.sh -h <master_ip> -p 7077 --webui-port 8080 --properties-file ha.conf`

in another note, this inserting this code on `/usr/local/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` does the same thing as the code above

```
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=master:2181,slave1:2181,slave2:2181 -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/home/usr/local/spark/spark"
```

#### Zookeeper Configs

I have this one on `/usr/local/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg`

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000

# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10

# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5

# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/home/dd/zookeeper/data/

# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
dataLogDir=/home/dd/zookeeper/logs/

server.1=master1:2888:3888
server.2=master2:2889:3889
server.3=master3:2890:3890
```

It is expected that all workers must be connect and having `alive` status to the newly elected master but only the worker with the same IP address is connected and having the `alive` status.